# Change orientation of line using HTML canvas fillRect()

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to use HTML canvas `fillRect()` to make a block with a diagonal line from upper right to bottom left.

I managed to create a block with a line from upper left to bottom right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    for(var i = 0; i < 300; ++i) {
      ctx.fillRect(i, i, 1, 1);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get what I want based on this code?

Comment: Why are you using `fillRect` to draw lines rather than `lineTo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it using `lineTo`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(300, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 300);
ctx.moveTo(0, 300);
ctx.lineTo(300, 0);
ctx.stroke();
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```